# Database not updating using php and jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery, database

Basically, I want the status to change based on the id. There's no error but it is not updating.

index.php

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.seatCharts-seat').click(function(){ 
       var id = jQuery(this).attr("id");          
        
        $seatid = id;

        $.post("class/booking.php",
        {
          seatid:$seatid
        },
        function(data, status){
          console.log('data',data);
          console.log('status',status);
          console.log($seatid);

        });
      });
  });
```

booking.php

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

class booking extends config{
    public $id;

    public function __construct($id){
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function editTask(){
        $con = $this->con();
        $sql = "UPDATE `tbl_booking` SET `status`= 'unavailable' WHERE `id` = $this->id";
        $data = $con->prepare($sql);

        if($data->execute()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: how or where are you getting the `seatid` in php?

Comment: public function generateRowOne(){
            $con = $this->con();
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_booking` LIMIT 18";
            $data = $con->prepare($sql);
            $data->execute();
            $result = $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach ($result as $data){
                echo "<div id='$data[id]' role='checkbox' aria-checked='false' focusable='true' class='seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell seat-class $data[status]'>$data[seat_no]</div>";
            }
        }

Comment: You're wide open to SQL injection. You should use a parameter in the prepared statement, not variable interpolation.

Comment: @RicaMostajo They mean where is the code that uses `$_POST['seatid']`?

Comment: Im sorry if im not answering your questions properly, I'm new at this and I really don't have any idea most of the time lol

Comment: `booking::__construct()` probably need to call `parent::__construct()`. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: PDO or mysqli? `WHERE id = ?` should be the SQL, then bind the value.

Comment: @user3783243 PDO, how do I bind the value?

Comment: @RicaMostajo `$data->execute(array($this->id))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 is to create a common file to handle all ajax related activities for the project. Say I would call it as myAjaxHandler.php

Then I would include the required class files are creates its instances to get the required methods called. Keep in mind when your projects get bigger it would be a bit difficult to maintain.

myAjaxHandler.php

```
<?php
require_once 'booking.php';

if(!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['seatid'])) {
    $booking = new booking($_POST['seatid']);
    $result = $booking->editTask();
    echo $result; // Would get 1 for true & 0 for false
}
```

Changes to ajax

```
$.post("path/to/myAjaxHandler.php", 
    { 
       seatid: $seatid 
    }, 
    function(data, status){
      console.log('data',data);
      console.log('status',status);
    });
```

Option 2 is to have the above `if` block inside the booking.php file itself.

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

if(!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['seatid'])) {
    $booking = new booking($_POST['seatid']);
    $result = $booking->editTask();
    echo $result; // Would get 1 for true & 0 for false
}

class booking extends config { ... }

//Ajax
$.post("path/to/booking.php", 
  { 
   seatid: $seatid 
  }, 
  function(data, status){
    console.log('data',data);
    console.log('status',status);
  });
```

Comment: " Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function booking::__construct(), 0 passed... " It is not getting the id from this " $seatid = jQuery(this).attr("id"); " Thank you for helping!

Comment: @RicaMostajo Pass the id when creating the instance as the constructor expects the id. Ive updated the answer. $booking = new booking($_POST['seatid']);

Comment: It worked!!! I can't thank you enough!!! I've been trying to figure out what to do for two days.